Cocompactness of $A$ in $K_\infty$
Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically irreducible curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of genus $g$. Fix a closed point $\infty\in X$ of degree $\delta$. We can write $X = \operatorname{Spec}(A)\cup \infty$ and $A$ plays the role of functions regular over finite part. Let $K$ be the function field, i.e. $K=$Frac$(A)$. Since $X$ is smooth, $O_{X,\infty}$ is a DVR and we have a discrete valuation $v_\infty$. We complete $K$ at $\infty$ using $v_\infty$, denoted by $K_\infty$. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer for $v_\infty$ and $O_\infty = \{x\in K_\infty: v_\infty(x)\geq 0\}$ the ring of integers.
There is a classical result saying that $K_\infty/A$ is compact by using Riemann-Roch theorem in this way: Consider $L(n\infty) = H^0(X,O_X(n\infty))$, then for $n$ large enough, we have $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_q}L(n\infty) = n\delta-g+1$. So, we can pick a suitable $d$ such that $A\to K_\infty\to K_\infty/\pi^dO_\infty$ is surjective and so $\pi^dO_\infty\to K_\infty/A$ is also surjective, hence finishes the proof.
I don't see why we can pick a such $d$ making these two maps surjective in general without know the structure of $A$ in terms of the uniformizer $\pi$. This is easy to understood when $g=0$ as $A = \mathbb{F}_q[t]$, $K_\infty = \mathbb{F}_{q^\delta}((1/t))$, $O_\infty = \mathbb{F}_{q^\delta}[[1/t]]$. In this case, we just pick $d=1$. But how is it working in the $g>1$ case, in which I am not clear how $A$ looks like in terms of $\pi$. Wondering if you have any thoughts on this.
